# Unclear notation in a book on Lie theory

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-bundle

In the SIAM book from Anderson and Ibragimov „Lie Bäcklund Transformations and Applications“, the following can be found in the very beginning:

„Consider the group $G$ of point transformations

$x^{'i} = f^i(x,u,\underset{1}{u};a)$, $i=1,\dots,N$,

$u^{'\alpha}= \phi^{\alpha}(x,u,\underset{1}{u};a)$, $\alpha=1,\dots,M$,

$u_i^{'\alpha}= \psi_i^{\alpha}(x,u,\underset{1}{u};a)$, $\alpha=1,\dots,M$, $i=1,\dots,N$

in the space of independent variables $(x,u,\underset{1}{u})$ where $a$ is a group parameter, $x=(x^1,\dots,x^N)\in\mathbb R^N$, $u=(u^1,\dots,u^M)\in\mathbb R^M$, $\underset{1}{u}=(u_1^1,u_2^1,\dots,u_N^M)\in\mathbb R^{NM}$ …“

Unfortunately, the notation is not explained.

What is the difference between $u$ and  $\underset{1}{u}$?
Has the underset 1 a specific meaning?

Comment: Note, just by looking at the dimensions you can guess that this is to do with tensor products. I haven't seen that notation before though

Comment: Here is a link to a paper from the authors of the book: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X77900981?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=72e1dec478a39a30

Comment: Thanks for the link... and/but it is invariably best to directly tell the _author(s)_ of a book or paper, rather than the title, since titles tend to be insufficient to distinguish. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett : that‘s true, I just edited the question accordingly.